# How to specify different file contents for different environments in elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Creating files on the server(s) by using config files in .ebextensions is awesome, ie

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/myfile" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    source: http://foo.bar/myfile
```

However, is there a mechanism to create different files for different environments?

My specific need is to provide a different elasticsearch config file for dev, staging & production.

Is the only answer to use commands in .ebextentions? If so is there a way to find out which environment I'm in when running the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually specify the environment name using the [custom environment properties](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.managing.html), e.g. use `PARAM1` to specify `dev`, `staging` or `production` (you can use your own keys as well.

To use those variables you need to use them inside the [`container_commands`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands):

```
container_commands:
  download-config:
    command: wget http://foo.bar/{$PARAM1}/config.ini
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. I had read about these too. Unfortunately the container_commands won't be able to write files outside of the application code. I need to be able access /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml and possibly other files within /etc

Comment: Afaik the container commands are run as the super user so I don't see how it can't have access to `/etc`. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: That is a very good point. I don't believe I have read that the container commands are run as a regular user, so I have probably assumed this. I'll give it a go and report back.